# API endpoint for google sheets

Tags: rest, google-sheets, oauth, get, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create an API endpoint to access a google spreadsheet I made in google sheets for a web application. I have enabled google sheets API in the API console and created OAuth 2.0 Client IDs credentials for it.

The google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest?apix=true) says that the endpoint, for a get request (which is all need), is

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}

But when I try to access it I get a 403 error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I can't find the API endpoint structure anywhere in the documentation. I don't know what credentials go where. And in the google API console it only gives me the option to create OAuth 2.0 Client IDs or Service Account.

Really not sure how to make a simple GET request to a public spreadsheet. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using to call the API? Have you tried the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)?

Comment: this is the endpoint i'm using https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}
but i'm not sure where the key goes

Comment: I am referring to the code you are using to build your request. Can you please share the snippet?

Comment: Hi @Alessandro, i worked it out. the structure for the API endpoint is

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${SHEET_ID}/values/Sheet1!A1:D1?key=${API_KEY}